# Need algorithm to detect pulse in singal data in R

Tags: r

I am pretty fresh in R so figured someone could have already thought of a more
elegant solution to this.
I have a data that looks like this:

[image]

I want to extract the **width of the pulse** given that:

- *my pulse would always have the highest value*
- *my pulse would always have highest width*
- *there is no notable noise before my pulse*
- *pulse resolution is 1e-09*

My approach so far is the one described below, but that seems to fail when data peak is closer to noise peak levels:

1. *Identify the start of the pulse by tracking the first point is series of 10 that is above %5 of maxima:*

```
sPoint <- which(rollapply(wave$mY, 10, function(x) min(x)>max(wave$mY)*0.05))[1]
```

2. *Identify where is the end point of the pulse by getting the subset of data that is above %50 of the maxima, define new treshold value %5 above min and again use rollapply:*

```
subData <- subset(wave,wave$mY>max(wave$mY)*0.5)
tresh <- min(subData$mY)+min(subData$mY)*0.05
ePoint <- subData$Time[which(rollapply(subData$mY, 10, function(x) max(x)<tresh))[1]]
```

3. *Subtract the two time values and round to 1e-09*

```
step <- 1e-09
pulseW <- ceiling((ePoint-sPoint)/step - 0.5)*step
```

This solution fails miserably when data peak is close to noise peak levels, so subset()-ing at some hardcoded percentage doesn't work.
**Can you point me to better algorithm / solution to this problem?**

Thank you

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/findpeaks the findpeaks function is probably a good starting point